# How to rename image filename and make same as title field value

Tags: hooks

Can somebody also help me to rename the image name same as title field?

I have a image content type where we have title and image field and when I submit the form I want to rename the image name same as the title field. This way I can make my image more meaningful by including keyword in the image name. Right now you can write about 'A' in the title field and you can upload images 'B' and that I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to do this using the [Filefield Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module. This will allow you to use tokens based on node fields to rename the file on upload.